# How can I select and display the most-used string

Tags: javascript, counting

I create a new application for comparison of exchange offices for scientific purposes.

I need to choose from JSON text, the most used value between (€,CHF,SEK,$,£) and display it as one of this values (EURO,FRANK,KORONA,DOLAR,FUNT).

```
function myFunction() {

    text = localStorage.getItem("userHistory");

    obj = JSON.parse(text);

    var iloscEuro = (text.split("€").length -1);

    var iloscCHF = (text.split("CHF").length -1);

    var iloscSEK = (text.split("SEK").length -1);

    var iloscDolar = (text.split("$").length -1);

    var iloscFunt = (text.split("£").length -1);

    alert(Math.max(iloscEuro, iloscCHF, iloscSEK, iloscDolar, iloscFunt));

}
```

Currently, the number of times the most popular currency is used is displayed.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `obj = JSON.parse(text);`? And why you do `-1`

Comment: how do you hope we can understand anything without having any data to test?

Comment: As @MisterJojo said, you should provide the structure if you'd like assistance. Many people can help you, but it's hard to interpret your model from what you've given us, and there's few people who want to spend the time to answer when they have to guess at something so important to the question. Even if they try and give you the right concept for your problem, it may not work with what you have, and no one wants to go back and forth while you explain what it is you're *really* looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that your JSON string probably has a built-in structure that would make it far more performant to parse than using `split()` which is extremely slow.

However, since I don't know what that structure is, I'll go with your chosen approach.

You can use something like the following code, which will [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) an array of currencies and return an array of objects. Each object will have a `currency` property and a `count` property. You can then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array in descending order by the `count` property, so the first item in your array will be equal to or greater than all others.

The advantage here is that you get the counts for all currencies, which may be useful if you have a tie between 2 or more currencies for the greatest representation.

```js
const text = `{"values": [ '€123', 'CHF123', 'CHF456', 'SEK123', '$123', '£123' ]}`;

const currencies = ["€", "CHF", "SEK", "$", "£"];

const counts = currencies
  .map(
    currency =>
      ({
        currency,
        count: text.split(currency).length -1,
      })
  )
  .sort(
    (l, r) =>
      r.count - l.count
  );

console.log( counts );
```

If you simply want the greatest, you can get it from your array:

```
counts[0].currency
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mapping table and the reduce method.

```js
const text = "CHF CHF CHF € €";
const mappingTable = { "€": "EURO", "CHF": "FRANK" };

let maxOccurenceCount = 0;
const mostFrequentKey = Object.keys(mappingTable).reduce((bestKeySoFar, currentKey) => {
    const currentOccurenceCount = text.split(currentKey).length - 1;
    if (currentOccurenceCount > maxOccurenceCount) {
      maxOccurenceCount = currentOccurenceCount;
      return currentKey;
    }
    return bestKeySoFar;
}, mappingTable[0]);

console.log(mappingTable[mostFrequentKey])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object literal with Symbols translation.
Than you could use `String.prototype.match()` to count occurrences in string

```js
const symb = {'€':'EURO', 'CHF':'FRANK', 'SEK':'KORONA', '$':'DOLAR', '£':'FUNT',};

function countExc(text) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(text), res = {};
  for(k in obj) res[symb[k]] = (obj[k].match(new RegExp(`\\${k}`,'g')) || []).length;
  return res;
}

console.log( countExc(`{"CHF":"1CHF 2CHF", "€":"100€", "$":"1$ 2$ 4$"}`) );
```